# angularjs unable to find templates directory, flask as backend

Tags: angularjs, flask, angularjs-directive

I am using flask as backend and angularjs on client-side

my directory structure:

dew:

```
  ->app.py

  ->templates
    ->hello.html
    ->test.html

  ->static
    ->js
      ->directives.py
    ->lib
      ->angular.js
```

my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response,render_template
@app.route("/aboutUs")
def aboutUs():
    return render_template("test.html", title="test page")
```

my directives.py file :

```
angular.module('components',[])
    .directive("helloWorld",function($scope,$log){
        $scope.$log = $log;
        return{
            restrict:"A",
            templateUrl:"templates/hello.html"
        }
    })

angular.module('testApp',['components'])
```

Flask was able to render the test.html template properly, but angular was showing  hello.html, template not found error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### 1. Jinja template

If `hello.html` contains Jinja2 markup then it is a template and needs to be rendered by Flask. Add an `@app.route` to render it.

```
@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return render_template("hello.html")
```

Then point to the `hello` URL in the Angular directive.

```
templateUrl: "{{ url_for('hello'}} }}"
```

#### 2. Angular template

If the file contains only HTML (no Jinja2 markup), then it is not a template. It should not be in the `templates` folder but **in the static folder**; like `static/angular_templates/hello.html`.

Then point to the static file in the directive.

```
templateUrl: "{{ url_for('static', filename='angular_templates/hello.html') }}"
```