# Not able to render index.html using Flask as backend with angular js [ Updated]

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

My App structure is like below :

```
--app
  --app.py
  --static
    --js
      --app.js
    --css
    --partial
      --home.html
  --templates
    --index.html
```

Already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756506/angularjs-unable-to-find-templates-directory-flask-as-backend) , but it is different

my **app.py**

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return send_file('static/partial/home.html')
    #tried with below as well
    #return make_response(open('static/partial/index.html').read())
```

my **app.js**

```
use strict';
var guts = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'ngCookies']);
```

my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appcontroller">
     <head>
     </head>
```

The error coming while hosting app on local server is :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\app\\templates/index.html' , i tried changing this backslash with other options , not luck
```

**P.S**
I dont want to use jinja templates
Also i am referencing [this](https://kkschick.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/setting-up-the-structure-and-routing-of-an-app-using-flask-and-angularjs/) blog as reference.
Any leads on this ?

[Updated] : final goal is to render home.html which is there @static/partial

Answer (score 1):

That should be `return render_template('index.html')`. Regardless of whether or not it actually has jinja template code, Flask won't be able to find it unless you specify it's a template file (or use `send_from_directory` directly).

If you really want to use `send_file` like in the blog post you linked, make the view function return `send_file(os.path.join('templates', 'index.html'))` which will take care of all the slash nonsense for you.

Comment: have you seen the reference link i have pasted in question , it seems they are rendering it also what if i dont wanna use Jinja templates , can't i achieve it ?

Comment: `render_template` is just being used for convenience; your `index.html` doesn't actually have any jinja code and thus will be sent as-is. The `send_file` method is much more brittle as it uses relative paths that could be invalid depending on how the app is run or installed.

Comment: thanks for the direction , I have update the question : can you put some points on that

Comment: Ah, then just change the send_file join to `'static', 'partial', 'index.html' `